# Is there a word for when you/someone seeks help with a problem from someone else, but then the problem is resolved/gone when the helper arrives?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests, proverb-requests

This is a situation I see my self first hand very often as someone who works in an IT related role. I also see it in other areas and experienced by seemingly everyone, but I don't know if there is a word for it. If not, I think we should make one!

For example: Your car is making a weird abnormal noise when you start it, and it predictably does this every single time you start it. However when you take it to a Mechanic and you start the car like any other time, and the noise is gone.

Maybe there's an idiom or proverb that describes this. I feel this is a common experience that should have more eloquent explaining what happened than saying "I swear I'm not crazy, it was just doing it before you came!"

Comment: The same term is used across a wide range of contexts (including software support). What professional "fixers" really hate is [***intermittent faults***.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermittent_fault) But there will be various alternatives (particularly, *colloquial* expressions, which may be domain-specific).

Answer (score 4):

In computer programming, we call this a "heisenbug"

> In computer programming jargon, a heisenbug is a software bug that seems to disappear or alter its behavior when one attempts to study it. The term is a pun on the name of Werner Heisenberg, the physicist who first asserted the observer effect of quantum mechanics, which states that the act of observing a system inevitably alters its state.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug)

I am not familiar with a more general term.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with the term, despite having spent many decades hunting this particular kind of bug myself. It raised a smile from me, but I wouldn't count on your average grease-monkey understanding it! ([Dilbert's legendary garbage man](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDH3XuxF_Qw) certainly would though! :)